# NPM module Is In /node_modules folder but cannot be found?

Tags: node.js, npm, md5, npm-install

I am having a bit of an issue getting the `md5` node module installed properly on an Ubuntu dev server I have setup.

(It works fine on my local windows machine, and I can install other modules with npm just fine on the dev server)

When I try and start a NodeJS application I am working on it fails stating that the `md5` module is not installed.

```
    // trying to start my application that depends on md5.
    drichardson@devwebserver:/var/www/node_app/meanapp$ node server.js
    module.js:340
        throw err;
        ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'md5'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node_app/node_modules/hashfile/index.js:7:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node_app/meanapp/app/controllers/exchanges.server.controller.js:15:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have tried installing this within my working directory:

```
    // Installing in working directory
    drichardson@devwebserver:/var/www/node_app/meanapp$ sudo npm install --save md5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/md5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/md5
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/md5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crypt
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/charenc
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/crypt
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/charenc
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer/-/is-buffer-1.0.2.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer/-/is-buffer-1.0.2.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/charenc
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/charenc/-/charenc-0.0.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/charenc/-/charenc-0.0.1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer/-/is-buffer-1.0.2.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer/-/is-buffer-1.0.2.tgz
    md5@2.0.0 node_modules/md5
    ├── charenc@0.0.1
    ├── crypt@0.0.1
    └── is-buffer@1.0.2
```

Even though the node module shows up in my /node_modules folder, it still throws the "Cannot find module `md5` "

```
    // MD5 In my node_modules folder:
    drichardson@devwebserver:/var/www/node_app/meanapp/node_modules$ ls -la | grep 'md5'
    drwxr-xr-x  2 drichardson drichardson 4096 Oct 30 13:53 md5
```

I have also tried:

*- Installing the module globally with "npm install -g md5"*
*- Cleaning the Cache and Reinstalling "npm cache clean"*
*- Reinstalling the application with "npm install"*

What else can I try to get this so that npm recognizes md5 as being installed?

Thanks,

Comment: check where is it being installed, as even when you try to install in working directory if one of its root has node_modules directory, it gets installed there instead of in working directory. I think installing globally with `-g` should have worked actually.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and the problem wasn't where the module was installed, but instead it was because the `main` property in the `package.json` file was not correctly set.  In my case it referred to a file that wasn't there.  Make sure that the `"main":"..."` is set correctly for the module.

If this is a module that you do not control, as a quick fix you can make the change in the nearest node_modules directory.  In our case this was located in the root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try clearing entire node_modules and installing everything again?

```
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
```

Comment: I tried this, it did not work I get the same issue with 'md5' module not being installed. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

In folder */var/www/node_app/node_modules/hashfile/*

run `npm install md5`

You tried this?

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being the version of Node and NPM that I was running locally vs in my Docker containers.

```sh
# Local versions:
$ node --version
v12.18.2
$ npm --version
6.14.10
```

I changed in my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:15-alpine3.12
#         ^^
# ...
```

to

```
FROM node:12-alpine3.12
#         ^^
# ...
```